# Origin of the name "Jesucristo"

Tags: etimología, sustantivos, nombres-propios, contracciones

The name **Jesus** translates simply as *Jesús*, and **Christ** as *Christo*.  So why is **Jesus Christ** translated as *Jesucristo* rather than *Jesús Cristo* or *Cristo Jesús*?

Google gives me a plethora of explanations for the origin of the name *Jesús* or the term *Cristo* (which are quite similar to the origins of the respective words in English), but I'm curious about the origin of the contraction *Jesucristo*.  So far my searching has found nothing about the history of this word.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The Latin **Iesus** is an irregular form of the 4th declension. (The Latin declensions are like verb conjugations in Spanish, but applied to nouns).

**Iesus** is in the singular *nominative* case: the "name" of the word (as seek it in the dictionary) and the form it takes when is grammatical nucleus of subject. **Iesum** is in singular *acusative* (like direct complement). And **Iesu** is the form that takes all another cases (*dative, genitive* and *ablative* singular and plural).

Since the formation of the Spanish language until the mid-20th century *all* Spanish speakers say the Latin name of Jesus Christ weekly in a ceremony: Mass. Consider the following passages of Mass in Latin:

> Grátia Dómini nostri **Iesu Christi**, et cáritas Dei, et communicátio Sancti Spíritus sit cum ómnibus vobis.
>
> ...exspectántes beátam spem et advéntum Salvatóris nostri **Iesu Christi**.
>
> Dómine **Iesu Christe**, qui dixísti Apóstolis tuis...

In the simplified version of the [Roman Missal of St. Pius V](http://www.rosarychurch.net/spanish/latin_y_espanol.html) in 1570 I count 3 mentions of *Iesu* and none of *Iesus* or *Iesum*. In a full version of [modern Latin Mass](http://www.collationes.org/de-ministerium-sacerdotale/subsidia-liturgica/item/678-folleto-para-seguir-la-celebraci%C3%B3n-de-la-santa-misa-en-lat%C3%ADn-con-traducci%C3%B3n-a-varios-idiomas) I count 10 mentions of *Iesu*, 5 *Iesum* and none of *Iesus*. (It's an approach, the text changes daily).

Consequently, we can say that there is not really a loss of -s sound *in the Spanish word "Jesús"*. What we have is a Latin cultism that led to the synthesis of two words in one. **Iesu Christi** became **Jesucristo**.

Until the eighteenth century remains the original orthographic form with two words separated by a space, by example this Spanish book titles:

- [Politica real y sagrada discurrida por vida de **Iesu Christo**](https://books.google.cl/books?id=pln5QQrAr9IC&dq=politica%20real%20y%20sagrada&hl=es&pg=PP11#v=onepage&q&f=false) (Juan Vela, 1675)
- [Vida de **Jesu Christo**, nuestro señor, hombre, maestro y redentor](https://books.google.cl/books?id=D6Cduor1hG8C&hl=es&pg=PP5#v=onepage&q&f=false) (Fernando de Valverde, 1687)

But in the late eighteenth century there is evidence that the words are coming together in one compound word. A hyphen shows the first step of this join:

- [Sermones de los Mysterios de N. Señor **Iesu-Christo**](https://books.google.cl/books?id=qeLAS8kIhmEC&lpg=PA198&ots=wh2sB7ukiq&hl=es&pg=PP5#v=onepage&q&f=false) (Louis Bourdaloue, traducción de Miguel del Castillo, 1778)
- [La Infancia de **Jesu-Christo**](https://books.google.cl/books?id=PBeB8RbPdqcC&hl=es&pg=PR5#v=onepage&q&f=false) (Gaspar Fernández Ávila, 1791)

In 1790, an edition of a book prefers to use the hyphen, and 27 years later, the new edition of 1817 already uses the modern form (and has even lost the H):

- [Conocimiento de **Jesu-Christo**](https://books.google.cl/books?id=9EfhC4HJu5UC&lpg=PA446&ots=sBRLCA-XF9&hl=es&pg=PP5#v=onepage&q&f=false) (trad. Francisco Antonio Alemán, 1790)
- [Conocimiento de **Jesucristo**](https://books.google.cl/books?id=WEKpk7WWC1kC&hl=es&pg=PP9#v=onepage&q&f=false) (trad. Francisco Antonio Alemán, 1817)

Then we could say that the current Spanish form *Jesucristo* is used since circa 1800. A good evidence of this transition is found in this book

- [Tratado de la Iglesia de Jesuchristo](https://books.google.cl/books?id=2Dkobdcg2QEC&lpg=PA383&ots=S2Sy_sspYC&hl=es&pg=PP7#v=onepage&q&f=false) (Felix de Amat, 1802)

in which among the hundreds of references to Jesuchristo, appear hidden 3 times *Jesu-Christo* with an hyphen.

Comment: This is exactly the type of answer I'm looking for!  I wonder if you can add some sources, especially for the second to last paragraph, about the origin of the two Spanish words.

Comment: Exactly. In medieval periods it was most common to see Jesus' name spelt *jheſu*. I'm currently transcribing a book from 1495 and it exclusively uses that spelling (*jheſsu chriſtu* in full, with a space)

Comment: @guifa, sorry, what means "with a sieve" in your comment?

Comment: @Rodrigo "with a **space**", stupid autocorrect on my phone (and no editing of comments)

Answer (score 2):

In many dialects (or forms, if you wish) of Spanish, the *S* before a consonant transforms into an aspirated sound very similar to the english *H*.
So imagine something like *Jesuhcristo* and it's only logical that it ends up like *Jesucristo*

* Yes, the *S* in *Cristo* could have suffered the same process, so there's a hole in my theory. :D

Comment: Interesting. Can you provide some additional examples where this is true?

Comment: Not sure, *jesucristo* is the only one I can think of right now. Anyway it's just speculation. But I'll post some if can remember.

Comment: It sounds like an interesting theory... but if that's the only case, then it's not much of a pattern :)  Yes, if you think of others, please let us know!

Comment: I cannot validate, but this does really sound feasible. The difference between the two *S*s is really the phonetic emphasis they get because of their position in the word. Sadly, I cannot come up with any other examples right now. I will ask a language expert and see what she has to tell me on this later.

Comment: @Flimzy: In spoken Spanish, even if not written, such a change occurs extremely frequently, and is well-documented in the literature as well.

Comment: That's right, I couldn't come up with another example of this getting to formal writing, but pretty common in spoken spanish, and it's very likely that Jesus was one of the most mentioned subjects in spanish literature at least in the past centuries.

Answer (score 2):

He encontrado una referencia en la [Enciclopedia Católica Online](http://ec.aciprensa.com/wiki/Origen_del_Nombre_de_Jesucristo) que menciona al libro *"Origin of the Name of Jesus Christ", Maas, Anthony. The Catholic Encyclopedia. Vol. 8. New York: Robert Appleton Company, 1910. http://www.newadvent.org/cathen/08374x.htm*.

Esta referencia incide en el hecho de que "Jesús" era un nombre común en la época y que "Cristo" era una denominación, por lo que "Jesucristo" es resultado de su uso conjunto.

> La palabra Jesus es la forma latina del griego Iesous, que a su vez es
>   la transliteración del hebreo Jeshua, o Joshua, o también Jehoshua,
>   que significa “Yahveh es salvación”. (...) El nombre griego está
>   relacionado con el verbo *iasthai*, sanar; (...) Si bien en el tiempo
>   de Cristo el nombre Jesús parece haber sido bastante común le fue
>   impuesto a Nuestro Señor por orden expresa de Dios (Lc. 1,31; Mt.
>   1,21), como señal de que el Niño estaba destinado a “salvar a su
>   pueblo de sus pecados.”
>
> La palabra *Christ*, *Christos*, equivalente griego para la palabra
>   hebrea *Messias*, significa “ungido”
>
> **Sólo luego de la Resurrección el título se convirtió gradualmente en nombre propio, y la expresión *Jesucristo* o *Cristo Jesús* se
>   convirtió en una sola designación.** (...)
>
> El uso del artículo definido antes de la palabra *Cristo* y su gradual
>   desarrollo hacia un nombre propio muestra que los cristianos
>   identificaban al portador de ese nombre con el Mesías prometido de los
>   judíos.

La caída de la `s` forma parte del proceso histórico de la evolución de las palabras a través de su uso. Sin embargo, no puedo encontrar una regla general que la explique con mayor detalle.

Answer (score 1):

lt might come from Latin, perhaps because all the declensions but two are Iesu (nominative Iesus, and accusative Iesum), v.g. Jesu Christi. This might have lead to a hyphenated use in Spanish as Jesu-Christo. The RAE erased the h. And, I don't know when or how, it got merged. 
(Still,  I realize it's just a theory. Somehow I managed to be sure,  so I checked and I'm editing this. I apologize.)

- Christ means Messiah, not king.

You can absolutely say/translate it as **Cristo Jesús**. It is perfectly fine, and perhaps more appropriate than Jesucristo.

You cannot say Jesús Cristo, even if it's right, because it is not commonplace at all. But I would agree and advocate for writing "**Jesu-Christo**" as it was before,

Answer (score 0):

In Spanish compound words (and I guess names too) the first word almost always ends in a vowel.

http://spanish.about.com/od/spanishvocabulary/a/compounds_2.htm

Besides this makes it a lot easier to say too!

Comment: Well, that doesn't say anything about what happens when the first words does _not_ end in a vowel.

Answer (score 0):

The term "Cristo Jesús" does occur in several places in the Bible.  For example, in Efesios 2:10.

https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Efesios+2%3A10&version=RVR1960

I think this follows the word order chosen in the original Greek.  The English translations do the same thing.  Paul sometimes uses one word order, sometimes the other.

As to why "Jesús Cristo" becomes "Jesucristo", I concur with the repsonders who theorize that it rolls off the tongue easier, and that's why it evolved that way.

Answer (score -1):

Most likely it is a mix of Spanish and Greek.

JesuCristo => Jesus + Cristo
Jesus (no explanation needed right?)
Cristo comes from greek Xristo, which was a way to refer to the kings of Israel, so at the end Jesucristo is some kind of "Jesus, the king".

Comment: This does not answer the question: why is it *Jesucristo* instead of *Jesuscristo*?